# Using noSQL in e-commerce server

Tags: nosql, e-commerce

e-commerce is a product of microsoft.As i gone through the product i came to know that it is mandatory to use SQL server along with e-commerce sever.i want to increase the speed of the retrival process and want to use a NoSQL database like MongoDB in place of SQL.Is that possible? please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

MongoDB can not be used as a drop-in replacement for SQL databases. It already starts with the different and incompatible query language.

But it goes on with them having a completely different way of handling data, which makes it superior in some roles, but inferior in others. Even when you would use some translation-middleware which mimics a SQL server and translates the query commands into the equivalents of the MongoDB database behind it and translates the response back, the performance would likely be a lot worse than with a native MSSQL database, because you would be using MongoDB in a way it wasn't meant to be used.

When you want to use MongoDB successfully, you completely need to change the way you model your data and the way you deal with it. This affects your whole application design. When you try to use MongoDB as if it were a relational database, you will be extremely disappointed.

The same applies to other NoSQL databases.

Also, not every problem is a good fit for every database technology. When it comes to eCommerce applications, you should really think twice before choosing a database technology which doesn't fully guarantee [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) in all situations. Most (not all!) SQL databases do, most (not all!) NoSQL databases don't.